# Почему JSLint просит указывать use strict ?

Tags: javascript, валидация

Доброго времени суток.
Например валидация даже простого кода

```
function x() {
};
```

Выдаст

> Missing 'use strict' statement.

Что такое `use strict` я знаю, как выключить проверку `strict` тоже.
Меня интересует другое- почему считается хорошим тоном указывать `use strict` ?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-моему, причина довольно прозаическая - JavaScript изначально был спроектирован не слишком верно, и ряд его возможностей стоило бы задвинуть куда подальше, но сделать это из соображений совместимости уже нельзя. Сам по себе этот язык весьма либерален к пользователю, закрывая глаза на некоторые ошибки, допускаемые программистом, начиная от возможности использования переменных без объявления и заканчивая возможностью "забыть" поставить точку с запятой.  А строгий режим представляет собой своеобразную таблетку, позволяющую писать более "чистый" код, не разрешая программисту делать некоторые совсем уж нехорошие вещи и приучая его писать корректный код изначально.

А вообще сам факт его наличия является своеобразным признанием допущенных ранее ошибок